# Ember publish unique asset filename for CDN freshness?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

In order to force updated static assets to load from a stubborn CDN, I'm looking for a method of publsihing each of my `src="assets/...` references in **app/index.html** to unique filename, in order to keep CDN distributions fresh.

Maybe in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css?version={{content-for 'version'}}">
```

And then somewhere else I might override a custom `content-for` value with a random number or a build tag.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: [Fingerprinting](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls) should help, did you try it?

Comment: I'm going to try Ember Fingerprinting, thanks! I believe that's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [Ember fingerprinting](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls).

It's enabled in production by default:

```
ember build --environment=production
```

This will result in (lines like) the following in **index.html** and corresponding asset file names:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.css" integrity="sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU= sha512-z4PhNX7vuL3xVChQ1m2AB9Yg5AULVxXcg/SpIdNs6c5H0NE8XYXysP+DGNKHfuwvY7kxvUdBeoGlODJ6+SfaPg==" >
```

To enable fingerprinting by default for all environments, add this to your `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  fingerprint: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this by configuring your `ember-cli-build.js` file. The defaults of this file is shown below:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    app: {
      html: 'index.html',
      css: {
        'app': '/assets/application-name.css'
      },
      js: '/assets/application-name.js'
    },
    vendor: {
      css: '/assets/vendor.css',
      js: '/assets/vendor.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Have a look at the [configuring output paths](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#configuring-output-paths) section of the [ember-cli user guide](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/).

Comment: This successfully changes the names of the output files but does *not* change the content of index.html, so it leaves me where I started. I believe Ember Fingerprinting is the answer, but haven't gotten to it yet.